# How can i remove the endline char from display text when displaying in a web browser control

Tags: c#

I am displaying text though a web browser control and at the end of each line it shows ¶, How can i remove this?

When i display the text in a rich textbox i can see the $Para, i want to remove that and but formatting, How can i achieve this?

**I display these text the say way:**

```
this.webPrevSQL.DocumentText = FinalPrev;
richTextBox1.Text = FinalPrev;
```

**Text displayed in rich edit:**

```
<span>EventType CREATE_PROCEDURE
&para;<br>PostTime 2012-06-18T14:56:19.870
&para;<br>SPID 63
&para;<br>ServerName MIDDEV1\DEV
&para;<br>LoginName devKoketso
&para;<br>UserName devKoketso
&para;<br>DatabaseName TestAudit
&para;<br>SchemaName dbo
&para;<br>ObjectName Admin
&para;<br>ObjectType PROCEDURE
&para;<br>TSQLCommand 
&para;<br>--alter table AdminLog add HostName varchar(128) NULL DEFAULT HOST_NAME()
&para;<br>
&para;<br>
&para;<br>
&para;<br>CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Admin]
```

**Text Displayed in web browser:**

```
EventType CREATE_PROCEDURE ¶
PostTime 2012-06-18T14:56:19.870 ¶
SPID 63 ¶
ServerName MIDDEV1\DEV ¶
LoginName devKoketso ¶
UserName devKoketso ¶
DatabaseName TestAudit ¶
SchemaName dbo ¶
ObjectName Admin ¶
ObjectType PROCEDURE ¶
TSQLCommand ¶
--alter table AdminLog add HostName varchar(128) NULL DEFAULT HOST_NAME() ¶
¶
¶
¶
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Admin] ¶
```

Comment: Which RichTextbox are you using?

Comment: just a normal one. i am going to remove the textbox later its just for test now

Comment: Just thought maybe it's the display options of the RichTextbox, maybe it is by default set up to display whitespace and you can somehow disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you tryed use `Replace` method on final string which you want to display on web?

```
FinalPrev.Replace("&para;","");
```

**Edit:**

try to change `<br>` to `<br/>`

Answer (score 1):

The `&para` at the beginning of each `<br>` block is actually the character ¶.
Remove it and try again.

Comment: ? could you show me what you trying to explain i don'y understand you?

Comment: You may have format issue between your browser and your text/code. Check the encoding of both and you might be able to get rid of the `&para`.